# Electric Field and Magnetic field of Guassian beam

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, optics

The center of the gaussian beam in glass has a beam power of 1 mW and a beam radius of 20 μm (micro meter). The wavelength of the light $\lambda_0$ is 1550 nm.

How can I find the electric field E and magnetic field H?

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer (since this looks like homework): remember that the power per unit area is given by the Poynting vector 
$$
\vec S = \frac1{\mu_0}\left(
\vec E \times \vec B
\right)
$$
and that the amplitudes of $E$ and $B$ for electromagnetic radiation are related by Maxwell's equations.